# Unexpected signal 11 vcpu-(0) error in vmware player

Tags: macos, vmware-player

I am using VMware player (version 7.1.0build2496824) and I had installed mac os X lion 10.7 as a virtual os.

When I start VMware player and login on the mac os X lion I get the following error:

```
Unexpected Signal - vcpu(0) error
```

Here is my log file

```
2015-03-25T11:29:50.472+05:45| vmx| I120: Vix: [20849 mainDispatch.c:1187]: VMAutomationPowerOff: Powering off.
2015-03-25T11:29:50.472+05:45| vmx| W110: /home/amit/vmware/Lion/Lion.vmx: Cannot remove symlink /var/run/vmware/amit_1001/1427262279779574_20849/configFile: No such file or directory
2015-03-25T11:29:50.472+05:45| vmx| I120: Policy_SavePolicyFile: invalid arguments to function.
2015-03-25T11:29:50.472+05:45| vmx| I120: PolicyVMX_Exit: Could not write out policies: 15.
2015-03-25T11:29:50.472+05:45| vmx| I120: WORKER: asyncOps=4 maxActiveOps=2 maxPending=0 maxCompleted=0
2015-03-25T11:29:50.491+05:45| vmx| I120: Vix: [20849 mainDispatch.c:4291]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=1, newAppState=1873, success=1 additionalError=0
2015-03-25T11:29:50.494+05:45| vmx| I120: Vix: [20849 mainDispatch.c:4291]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=0, newAppState=1870, success=1 additionalError=0
2015-03-25T11:29:50.494+05:45| vmx| I120: Transitioned vmx/execState/val to poweredOff
2015-03-25T11:29:50.494+05:45| vmx| I120: Vix: [20849 mainDispatch.c:4291]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=0, newAppState=1870, success=0 additionalError=0
2015-03-25T11:29:50.494+05:45| vmx| I120: Vix: [20849 mainDispatch.c:4330]: Error VIX_E_FAIL in VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished(): Unknown error
2015-03-25T11:29:50.495+05:45| vmx| I120: Vix: [20849 mainDispatch.c:4291]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=0, newAppState=1870, success=1 additionalError=0
2015-03-25T11:29:50.495+05:45| vmx| I120: Transitioned vmx/execState/val to poweredOff
2015-03-25T11:29:50.495+05:45| vmx| I120: VMIOP: Exit
2015-03-25T11:29:50.524+05:45| vmx| I120: Vix: [20849 mainDispatch.c:842]: VMAutomation_LateShutdown()
2015-03-25T11:29:50.524+05:45| vmx| I120: Vix: [20849 mainDispatch.c:792]: VMAutomationCloseListenerSocket. Closing listener socket.
2015-03-25T11:29:50.524+05:45| vmx| I120: Flushing VMX VMDB connections
2015-03-25T11:29:50.524+05:45| vmx| I120: VmdbDbRemoveCnx: Removing Cnx from Db for '/db/connection/#1/'
2015-03-25T11:29:50.524+05:45| vmx| I120: VmdbCnxDisconnect: Disconnect: closed pipe for pub cnx '/db/connection/#1/' (0)
2015-03-25T11:29:50.525+05:45| vmx| I120: VigorTransport_ServerDestroy: server destroyed.
2015-03-25T11:29:50.530+05:45| vmx| I120: VMX exit (0).
2015-03-25T11:29:50.530+05:45| vmx| I120: AIOMGR-S : stat o=5 r=15 w=0 i=0 br=245760 bw=0
2015-03-25T11:29:50.541+05:45| vmx| I120: OBJLIB-LIB: ObjLib cleanup done.
2015-03-25T11:29:50.541+05:45| vmx| I120: FileTrack_Exit: done
```

Could anyone help me solving this error please?

Comment: tried installing in another system?

Comment: please can u suggest me about another system???

Comment: i mean in another computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try troubleshooting using following instructions if after too issue prevails get support request from [vmware](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=2006985)  :

- Confirm that the folder or directory is still accessible by the user
  creating the virtual machine.
- If the virtual machine contains any non-preallocated disks, verify
  that the volume storing the disks did not run out of free space.
- Perform a repair of the virtual disk.
- Verify there are no problems with the host's file system by
  performing a disk check on your hard drives.
- Verify that you are running the latest version of the VMware product
  in use.
- Completely reinstall the VMware product. If you are using an older
  version of the product, install the latest version.
- Memory defects at host can cause failures or unexpected software
  behavior.
- Ensure that the graphic drivers are up to date on the host physical
  machine.
- Confirm that a resource, such as the disk, is not too busy to
  respond, thus causing the problem.
- In some circumstances, you can experience these errors when the
  system is very low on resources.
- Confirm that no other virtualization software is running
  simultaneously.